# What is the Keijo manga release cycle?

Tags: keijo

Not sure if my phrasing is correct but does anyone know the manga release cycle of Keijo!!!! (Hip whip girl)?

I haven't seen an issue for it in a while and the source I use to read it seems to only update monthly.

Does the manga actually release monthly? And how can I find this information for future series that I read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keijo!!!!!!!!) it says

> ***Keijo!!!!!!!!*** (Japanese: 競女!!!!!!!!, lit. "Competitive Girl"), also known as ***Hip Whip Girl***, is a Japanese sports manga series by Daichi Sorayomi. It has been serialized in Shogakukan's shōnen manga magazine Weekly Shōnen Sunday since July 2013 and has been collected in fourteen tankōbon volumes.

and confirming [Shogakukan's Weekly Shōnen Sunday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekly_Sh%C5%8Dnen_Sunday)

> ***Weekly Shōnen Sunday*** (Japanese: 週刊少年サンデー Hepburn: *Shūkan Shōnen Sandē*) is a weekly shōnen manga magazine published in Japan by Shogakukan since March 1959. Contrary to its title, Weekly Shōnen Sunday issues are released on Wednesdays.

now looking at the [wikia](http://keijo.wikia.com/wiki/Manga) there is 159 Chapters with 151 Chapters in tankōbon format.

> ***Keijo!!!!!!!!*** manga series is written and drawn by Daichi Sorayomi. It has been serialized in Weekly Shōnen Sunday since July 2013 and has been collected in twelve tankōbon volumes along with 151 chapters.

my number of 159 is based off that at the end of the page the last chapter number is 159. also you can see the tankōbon volumes vary in their release dates.

starting at [the first Wednesday of July 2013 to the Wednesday just past (04/01/2017)](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=03&m1=07&y1=2013&d2=04&m2=1&y2=2017) we can see there has been 183 weeks passed. now if 1 chapter of Keijo!!!!!!!! is released every week there is a discrepancy of 24 weeks (`183-159 = 24`) but these can be accounted for by holidays and that i don't know when in July the first chapter of Keijo!!!!!!!! came out (so it may not have been 03/07/2013).

with this information we can roughly guess that Keijo!!!!!!!! is being released weekly in each issue of Weekly Shōnen Sunday in Japan with some breaks for holidays. of cause without having the issues themselves i can't be for certain that each issue has had 1 chapter of Keijo!!!!!!!!

as i pointed out in my [comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/38260/what-is-the-keijo-manga-release-cycle/38266?noredirect=1#comment52058_38266) the [Mangaupdates page](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=101987) has a "releases" section but these are the scanlation releases as such the release of these are  not predefined especially since these are unofficial. not to mention that the this list should stop being updated if/when Keijo!!!!!!!! is officially licensed in English to which would generally mean they would be released in tankōbon format

Answer (score 2):

Keijo is published in "Shuukan Shounen Sunday", which is a weekly magazine.

To figure out what cycle a manga follows, you can use mangaupdates, which will show you the serialization magazine for each manga. From there you can just google the name of the magazine, and usually the english title will be an answer by itself, like in this case where "Shuukan" translates to "Weekly".

https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=101987

Comment: to point out the "releases" on the page are the Scanlations, not the original releases in Japan. the useful bit of info you get out of Mangaupdate is that it isn't released in English yet offically

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty much useless to to check the release page to figure out the schedule. Scanlators are just people that put out releases in their free time, and while some may consistently translate directly from fresh magazine scans, several prefer to wait until whole volumes are published (usually up to half a year after the magazine scans in case of weekly manga) so that they can work on better scans. That's also why a lot of translated series are behind japanese releases by several volumes (Kengan Ashura & Keijo are such cases).